# Is there a way to see a separate taskbar for the VM in VMWare Unity?

Tags: vmware, vmware-unity

The question's in the title - I'd like to have a separate taskbar for my VM, preferably one that I can dock to a different part of the screen (but at all would be nice).

Third-party utilities are also welcome.  The host and guest are both Windows 7 Professional x64.